# Third party libraries in Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Trying to add custom library mylib.jar that is not builded with Maven to Eclipse Maven Java project.:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>caen</groupId>
        <artifactId>CAENRFIDLibrary</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}${file.separator}..${file.separator}mylib.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

library is placed in eclipse workspace folder and I couldn't find nice way to tell Maven about this location. That is why `${project.basedir}${file.separator}..${file.separator}` was used.

Looks like it works, but is it correct way of placing dependencies in such way and such location? What is common practice of placing libraries in Maven project?

Comment: Is `${project.basedir}\..\mylib.jar` not working ?

Comment: @vizsatiz:  The OP said it did, but they're wondering if this is a conventional way to pull in non-Maven artifacts.